# transform a polygon class sf to class owin in r

Tags: r, geospatial, polygon, spatial, r-sf

My polygon has the following structure:

```
t1 = structure(list(WindfarmId = "NO39", Name = "Sørlige Nordsjø I", 
    Country = "NO", Status = 99L, WindfarmStatus = "Development Zone", 
    StatusComments = NA_character_, CapacityMWMin = 500, CapacityMWMax = 1500, 
    NoTurbinesMin = NA_integer_, NoTurbinesMax = NA_integer_, 
    Comments = "In 2013, NVE divided considered offshore wind zones into three categories. This area is considered Category A.\r\n\r\nCategory A: Wind power development within the zone \r\nis technically and economically feasible, and will have \r\nrelatively few negative impacts. Grid connection is possible \r\nbefore 2025. \r\n\r\nCategory B: Wind power development within the zone will \r\nhave challenges related to either technical aspects or conflict of interests/negative impacts. The challenges might \r\nbe resolved in the future through technology development, \r\ngrid measures and/or mitigation measures. NVE considers \r\nthat zones in this category can be opened when technology \r\nmatures, or when existing use of the areas changes. \r\n\r\nCategory C: Wind power development within the zone represents greater challenges than in the other two categories. \r\nConflicts of interest in the areas are not easily resolved. \r\nForeseen negative impacts are still considered acceptable. Zones in this category should not be opened at the \r\nexpense of zones in the two other categories.\r\n\r\nA 2018 review of the areas put Utsira Nord, and Sørlige Nordsjø I/II forward as recommended areas for opening up for offshore wind. The 2019 consultation hearing however did not include Sørlige Nordsjø I. Although Sørlige Nordsjø I has less conflict with shipping and lower environmental risk, Sørlige Nordsjø II is closer to the European power system, is a larger area and has fewer allocated petroleum production licences.", 
    TurbineMWMin = NA_real_, TurbineMWMax = NA_real_, OtherNames = "Offshore wind - study area; Category A", 
    CountryName = "Norway", Lat = 57.4203547589749, Lon = 3.5335822891109, 
    IsEstimatedLocation = 0L, IsOnHold = 0L, OffshoreConsStartDate = structure(NA_real_, class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), ProjFullCommDate = structure(NA_real_, class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), Georegion = "Europe", Developers = "Norges vassdrags- og energidirektorat", 
    Owners = NA_character_, Operators = NA_character_, WaterDepthMinM = 58, 
    WaterDepthMaxM = 72, GISFILE = "EU_SCRE_WindFarms_PN_4C_230110_4258", 
    Shape_Length = 2.25250768130164, Shape_Area = 0.203134377892303, 
    Shape = structure(list(structure(list(list(structure(c(4.02249908400006, 
    3.14500045800003, 3.04527854900005, 3.92694473300003, 4.02249908400006, 
    57.3724994670001, 57.250833512, 57.470277787, 57.5883331310001, 
    57.3724994670001), .Dim = c(5L, 2L)))), class = c("XY", "MULTIPOLYGON", 
    "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_MULTIPOLYGON", "sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 3.04527854900005, 
    ymin = 57.250833512, xmax = 4.02249908400006, ymax = 57.5883331310001
    ), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(input = "ETRS89", 
        wkt = "GEOGCRS[\"ETRS89\",\n    DATUM[\"European Terrestrial Reference System 1989\",\n        ELLIPSOID[\"GRS 1980\",6378137,298.257222101,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n    PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n        ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic latitude (Lat)\",north,\n            ORDER[1],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic longitude (Lon)\",east,\n            ORDER[2],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"unknown\"],\n        AREA[\"Europe - ETRS89\"],\n        BBOX[32.88,-16.1,84.17,40.18]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",4258]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L), 
    label = list(structure("Name: Sørlige Nordsjø I<br>Status: Development Zone<br>Capacity: 500[MW]<br>Owners: NA<br>", html = TRUE, class = c("html", 
    "character")))), sf_column = "Shape", agr = structure(c(WindfarmId = NA_integer_, 
Name = NA_integer_, Country = NA_integer_, Status = NA_integer_, 
WindfarmStatus = NA_integer_, StatusComments = NA_integer_, CapacityMWMin = NA_integer_, 
CapacityMWMax = NA_integer_, NoTurbinesMin = NA_integer_, NoTurbinesMax = NA_integer_, 
Comments = NA_integer_, TurbineMWMin = NA_integer_, TurbineMWMax = NA_integer_, 
OtherNames = NA_integer_, CountryName = NA_integer_, Lat = NA_integer_, 
Lon = NA_integer_, IsEstimatedLocation = NA_integer_, IsOnHold = NA_integer_, 
OffshoreConsStartDate = NA_integer_, ProjFullCommDate = NA_integer_, 
Georegion = NA_integer_, Developers = NA_integer_, Owners = NA_integer_, 
Operators = NA_integer_, WaterDepthMinM = NA_integer_, WaterDepthMaxM = NA_integer_, 
GISFILE = NA_integer_, Shape_Length = NA_integer_, Shape_Area = NA_integer_, 
label = NA_integer_), .Label = c("constant", "aggregate", "identity"
), class = "factor"), row.names = 1287L, class = c("sf", "data.frame"
))
```

I'm trying to use the `spatstat.geom` package to convert `t1` to class `owin` object :

```
t1_owin = as.owin(t1)
Error in as.owin.sfc_MULTIPOLYGON(st_cast(W, "MULTIPOLYGON"), ...) : 
  Only projected coordinates may be converted to spatstat class objects
```

And the coordinates in `t1` are lat/lng :

```
st_coordinates(t1)
            X        Y L1 L2 L3
[1,] 4.022499 57.37250  1  1  1
[2,] 3.145000 57.25083  1  1  1
[3,] 3.045279 57.47028  1  1  1
[4,] 3.926945 57.58833  1  1  1
[5,] 4.022499 57.37250  1  1  1
```

How do I project the `t1` to UTM in order to be able to get my `owin` object ?!

Comment: you need to use `st_transform(t1, crs = "YOUR CRS VALUE")` to convert them to your required CRS

Comment: @SymbolixAU, but the problem is I want it as `utm` and therefore I need to know the zone, which I don't !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `crsuggest` to get the right CRS (also the corresponding UTC if you need) and project your `sf` object so you can make your `owin`. Full workflow:

```r
t1 = structure(list(WindfarmId = "NO39", Name = "Sørlige Nordsjø I", 
                    Country = "NO", Status = 99L, WindfarmStatus = "Development Zone", 
                    StatusComments = NA_character_, CapacityMWMin = 500, CapacityMWMax = 1500, 
                    NoTurbinesMin = NA_integer_, NoTurbinesMax = NA_integer_, 
                    Comments = "In 2013, NVE divided considered offshore wind zones into three categories. This area is considered Category A.\r\n\r\nCategory A: Wind power development within the zone \r\nis technically and economically feasible, and will have \r\nrelatively few negative impacts. Grid connection is possible \r\nbefore 2025. \r\n\r\nCategory B: Wind power development within the zone will \r\nhave challenges related to either technical aspects or conflict of interests/negative impacts. The challenges might \r\nbe resolved in the future through technology development, \r\ngrid measures and/or mitigation measures. NVE considers \r\nthat zones in this category can be opened when technology \r\nmatures, or when existing use of the areas changes. \r\n\r\nCategory C: Wind power development within the zone represents greater challenges than in the other two categories. \r\nConflicts of interest in the areas are not easily resolved. \r\nForeseen negative impacts are still considered acceptable. Zones in this category should not be opened at the \r\nexpense of zones in the two other categories.\r\n\r\nA 2018 review of the areas put Utsira Nord, and Sørlige Nordsjø I/II forward as recommended areas for opening up for offshore wind. The 2019 consultation hearing however did not include Sørlige Nordsjø I. Although Sørlige Nordsjø I has less conflict with shipping and lower environmental risk, Sørlige Nordsjø II is closer to the European power system, is a larger area and has fewer allocated petroleum production licences.", 
                    TurbineMWMin = NA_real_, TurbineMWMax = NA_real_, OtherNames = "Offshore wind - study area; Category A", 
                    CountryName = "Norway", Lat = 57.4203547589749, Lon = 3.5335822891109, 
                    IsEstimatedLocation = 0L, IsOnHold = 0L, OffshoreConsStartDate = structure(NA_real_, class = c("POSIXct", 
                                                                                                                   "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), ProjFullCommDate = structure(NA_real_, class = c("POSIXct", 
                                                                                                                                                                                            "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), Georegion = "Europe", Developers = "Norges vassdrags- og energidirektorat", 
                    Owners = NA_character_, Operators = NA_character_, WaterDepthMinM = 58, 
                    WaterDepthMaxM = 72, GISFILE = "EU_SCRE_WindFarms_PN_4C_230110_4258", 
                    Shape_Length = 2.25250768130164, Shape_Area = 0.203134377892303, 
                    Shape = structure(list(structure(list(list(structure(c(4.02249908400006, 
                                                                           3.14500045800003, 3.04527854900005, 3.92694473300003, 4.02249908400006, 
                                                                           57.3724994670001, 57.250833512, 57.470277787, 57.5883331310001, 
                                                                           57.3724994670001), .Dim = c(5L, 2L)))), class = c("XY", "MULTIPOLYGON", 
                                                                                                                             "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_MULTIPOLYGON", "sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 3.04527854900005, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                               ymin = 57.250833512, xmax = 4.02249908400006, ymax = 57.5883331310001
                                                                                                                             ), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(input = "ETRS89", 
                                                                                                                                                                      wkt = "GEOGCRS[\"ETRS89\",\n    DATUM[\"European Terrestrial Reference System 1989\",\n        ELLIPSOID[\"GRS 1980\",6378137,298.257222101,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n    PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n        ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic latitude (Lat)\",north,\n            ORDER[1],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic longitude (Lon)\",east,\n            ORDER[2],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"unknown\"],\n        AREA[\"Europe - ETRS89\"],\n        BBOX[32.88,-16.1,84.17,40.18]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",4258]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L), 
                    label = list(structure("Name: Sørlige Nordsjø I<br>Status: Development Zone<br>Capacity: 500[MW]<br>Owners: NA<br>", html = TRUE, class = c("html", 
                                                                                                                                                                "character")))), sf_column = "Shape", agr = structure(c(WindfarmId = NA_integer_, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        Name = NA_integer_, Country = NA_integer_, Status = NA_integer_, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        WindfarmStatus = NA_integer_, StatusComments = NA_integer_, CapacityMWMin = NA_integer_, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        CapacityMWMax = NA_integer_, NoTurbinesMin = NA_integer_, NoTurbinesMax = NA_integer_, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        Comments = NA_integer_, TurbineMWMin = NA_integer_, TurbineMWMax = NA_integer_, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        OtherNames = NA_integer_, CountryName = NA_integer_, Lat = NA_integer_, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        Lon = NA_integer_, IsEstimatedLocation = NA_integer_, IsOnHold = NA_integer_, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        OffshoreConsStartDate = NA_integer_, ProjFullCommDate = NA_integer_, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        Georegion = NA_integer_, Developers = NA_integer_, Owners = NA_integer_, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        Operators = NA_integer_, WaterDepthMinM = NA_integer_, WaterDepthMaxM = NA_integer_, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        GISFILE = NA_integer_, Shape_Length = NA_integer_, Shape_Area = NA_integer_, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        label = NA_integer_), .Label = c("constant", "aggregate", "identity"
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        ), class = "factor"), row.names = 1287L, class = c("sf", "data.frame"
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        ))

library(sf)
#> Warning: package 'sf' was built under R version 4.1.3
#> Linking to GEOS 3.10.2, GDAL 3.4.1, PROJ 7.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(spatstat.geom)
#> Warning: package 'spatstat.geom' was built under R version 4.1.3
#> Loading required package: spatstat.data
#> Warning: package 'spatstat.data' was built under R version 4.1.3
#> spatstat.geom 3.0-3

as.owin(t1)
#> Error in as.owin.sfc_MULTIPOLYGON(st_cast(W, "MULTIPOLYGON"), ...): Only projected coordinates may be converted to spatstat class objects

# This is because
st_is_longlat(t1)
#> [1] TRUE

# So use a projection
candidates <- crsuggest::suggest_crs(t1)

candidates
#> # A tibble: 10 x 6
#>    crs_code crs_name                        crs_type  crs_gcs crs_units crs_pr~1
#>    <chr>    <chr>                           <chr>       <dbl> <chr>     <chr>   
#>  1 3043     ETRS89 / UTM zone 31N (N-E)     projected    4258 m         +proj=u~
#>  2 25831    ETRS89 / UTM zone 31N           projected    4258 m         +proj=u~
#>  3 23031    ED50 / UTM zone 31N             projected    4230 m         +proj=u~
#>  4 3035     ETRS89-extended / LAEA Europe   projected    4258 m         +proj=l~
#>  5 3034     ETRS89-extended / LCC Europe    projected    4258 m         +proj=l~
#>  6 32631    WGS 84 / UTM zone 31N           projected    4326 m         +proj=u~
#>  7 32431    WGS 72BE / UTM zone 31N         projected    4324 m         +proj=u~
#>  8 32231    WGS 72 / UTM zone 31N           projected    4322 m         +proj=u~
#>  9 3832     WGS 84 / PDC Mercator           projected    4326 m         +proj=m~
#> 10 3576     WGS 84 / North Pole LAEA Russia projected    4326 m         +proj=l~
#> # ... with abbreviated variable name 1: crs_proj4

# For the sake of example, I just choose the top 1, but you may want another
t1_proj <- st_transform(t1, as.numeric(candidates$crs_code[1]))

t1_proj
#> Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 31 fields
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 502715.8 ymin: 6345317 xmax: 561491.4 ymax: 6383258
#> Projected CRS: ETRS89 / UTM zone 31N (N-E)
#>      WindfarmId              Name Country Status   WindfarmStatus
#> 1287       NO39 Sørlige Nordsjø I      NO     99 Development Zone
#>      StatusComments CapacityMWMin CapacityMWMax NoTurbinesMin NoTurbinesMax
#> 1287           <NA>           500          1500            NA            NA
#>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           Comments
#> 1287 In 2013, NVE divided considered offshore wind zones into three categories. This area is considered Category A.\r\n\r\nCategory A: Wind power development within the zone \r\nis technically and economically feasible, and will have \r\nrelatively few negative impacts. Grid connection is possible \r\nbefore 2025. \r\n\r\nCategory B: Wind power development within the zone will \r\nhave challenges related to either technical aspects or conflict of interests/negative impacts. The challenges might \r\nbe resolved in the future through technology development, \r\ngrid measures and/or mitigation measures. NVE considers \r\nthat zones in this category can be opened when technology \r\nmatures, or when existing use of the areas changes. \r\n\r\nCategory C: Wind power development within the zone represents greater challenges than in the other two categories. \r\nConflicts of interest in the areas are not easily resolved. \r\nForeseen negative impacts are still considered acceptable. Zones in this category should not be opened at the \r\nexpense of zones in the two other categories.\r\n\r\nA 2018 review of the areas put Utsira Nord, and Sørlige Nordsjø I/II forward as recommended areas for opening up for offshore wind. The 2019 consultation hearing however did not include Sørlige Nordsjø I. Although Sørlige Nordsjø I has less conflict with shipping and lower environmental risk, Sørlige Nordsjø II is closer to the European power system, is a larger area and has fewer allocated petroleum production licences.
#>      TurbineMWMin TurbineMWMax                             OtherNames
#> 1287           NA           NA Offshore wind - study area; Category A
#>      CountryName      Lat      Lon IsEstimatedLocation IsOnHold
#> 1287      Norway 57.42035 3.533582                   0        0
#>      OffshoreConsStartDate ProjFullCommDate Georegion
#> 1287                  <NA>             <NA>    Europe
#>                                 Developers Owners Operators WaterDepthMinM
#> 1287 Norges vassdrags- og energidirektorat   <NA>      <NA>             58
#>      WaterDepthMaxM                             GISFILE Shape_Length Shape_Area
#> 1287             72 EU_SCRE_WindFarms_PN_4C_230110_4258     2.252508  0.2031344
#>                               Shape
#> 1287 MULTIPOLYGON (((561491.4 63...
#>                                                                                           label
#> 1287 Name: Sørlige Nordsjø I<br>Status: Development Zone<br>Capacity: 500[MW]<br>Owners: NA<br>


# And now

as.owin(t1_proj)
#> window: polygonal boundary
#> enclosing rectangle: [502715.8, 561491.4] x [6345317, 6383258] units
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>